# Suggest a tizen tv model which support (17AV_BD, 17TV_PREMIUM and 17TV_STANDARD) features

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

We have created a application for samsung tizen tv and submit on samsung tizen store.

After application verification by tizen team they provide us following results:
1) The application is approved in 15TV_PREMIUM, 15TV_STANDARD1, 15TV_STANDARD2, 16TV_PREMIUM, 16TV_STANDARD1 and 16TV_STANDARD2 models.

2) We got some defects in application for 17AV_BD, 17TV_PREMIUM and 17TV_STANDARD models.

Can any one suggest us a tizen tv model which support these models (17AV_BD, 17TV_PREMIUM and 17TV_STANDARD) features, So we can find defects easily and resolve issues ?

Answer (score -1):

See a table
, and you'll see that you have to use TV extension 3.0 or higher for the models.

[image: picture]

[a full view of the table on a site](http://tigertv.ru/en/samsung-tv-model-code/)